# Integer Array to Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to add an **int array into a vector**. No matter what I do, the debugger indicates the new vector element is simply "0".

```
std::vector< int * > level_collection;
for( auto & i : levels )
{
     auto size = std::get< 1 >(i).size();
     int level_data[size];
     for( size_t x = 0; x < size; x ++ )
     {
          level_data[x] = std::get< 1 >(i)[x];
     }

     for( auto x : level_data)
     {
          std::cout << x << std::endl; // This works. All the values print correctly. So it did store the information as it should.
     }

     level_collection.push_back( level_data );
 }
 for( auto & i : level_collection)
 {
     std::cout << i[1] << std::endl; // This prints ALL 0s. Despite the new element not having that value.
 }
```

I've been looking hours for a solution. I can't seem to find any.

What I've tried:

- Changing the location of level_data so it's not always reinitialized every time.
- Removing level_data and instead adding a new element to level_collection and copying the values returned in std::get directly into the vector
- Checked through the debugger and output that level_data does indeed return the correct array with the correct values. However, the moment it's added to level_collection, it turns to 0. (Doesn't matter if I try the other things I mentioned above)

I'm sure there's an easy solution here. I might just be overlooking something.

**Edit:** I unfortunately cannot use std::array in this assignment. We were told to work off of what's available. The function level_collection gets passed to is a "const int *"

Comment: Which int array are you to add to which vector here? I'm assuming `level_data` to `level_collection`?

Comment: @user3684240 level_data gets added to level_collection.

Comment: Is `size` a constant expression? If not, `int level_data[size];` is not standard C++. Also, `level_data`'s "pointer" you put in the vector is invalid outside the scope in which `level_data` is declared.

Comment: And what is `v_levels_output`?

Comment: Consider using `std::array`. Each array, that you `push_back`ed gets destroyed at the end of each loop iteration. Hence, each pointer is a dangling pointer, dereferencing which, leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @user3684240 level_collection, I changed something mid-way as I wrote the question. My bad.

Comment: When you do `int level_data[size];`, you are creating an array in your scope, which gets deleted after that for. Try instead doing `int *level_data= new int[size];` or something like that.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Unfortunately, what I have to use this vector for requires an int array.

Comment: @boop_bop_scoop "_what I have to use this vector for requires an int array._" So.. Why `std::array<int, size>` doesn't work for you?

Comment: The lifetime of `level_data` ends at the closing bracket of the `for` loop so you need to rethink what you're doing. You could use `new []` for each array but then you're responsible for  calling `delete []` to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: `std::vector< int * > level_collection;` -- This is not an `int` array.  You started off all wrong.  Array doesn't mean "I must use pointers".

Comment: @AlexanderIrribarra I did follow-up with this previously as I mentioned in the original post. I did try it again except with your proposal of creating the array. Instead, but the results are still the same.

Comment: *I'm trying to add an int array into a vector.* -- Well, why not do what you are stating?  `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> vectArray;...vectArray.push_back(std::array<int, 3>());` -- There you go -- an int array added to a vector.  If it's anything else, then what you're describing in the first sentence of your question is not what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius In my response to you, I just explained that the function that I'm passing level_collection to does not accept that. It will only accept "const int *". Using std::array is the ideal solution for me too, if I could use it, I would.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie See above. It does not accept it. If I use an std::array instead, the above code works perfectly fine in terms of doing what it should. However, it won't be able to pass through the function I need it for (and I can't change the function itself). Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @boop_bop_scoop -- *I'm sure there's an easy solution here. I might just be overlooking something.* -- You are overlooking something -- that something is that **arrays are dumb**.  You can hardly do anything with them other than declaring them, assign each element, and get each element.  You can't assign an array to an array, you can't pass an array to a function that takes a pointer and get the number of elements from it, etc.  That's why `std::array` was created, so that these limitations need not occur.  Look at the first line of your attempt -- you went into using `int*`, not arrays.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't disagree with you. But as I've said several times, I unfortunately do not have a choice with this specific assignment. If you have an idea for a solution besides changing the criteria of what I cannot change, please share. Thanks for your help in any case..

Comment: @boop_bop_scoop  You have `int *`, and that is *not* an array.  So what were you going to do with that `int *`?  It is not clear.  Second, your attempt of creating an array with a variable size is not valid C++, as stated by a previous comment.  Third, you say you must "work off of what's available", but what does that really mean?  Does it mean you can't wrap that pointer into a struct yourself and use what you created?  One "solution" would be just to create a `struct`, stick that pointer in it as a member, and `push_back` the struct.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I simply need to have a vector that points to different integer arrays. That's it. That should answer your first two points. In regards to the 3rd one, this is an assignment and what was given to us. We cannot use std::array or any other method. We have to simply work from **what's available**. We can't use anything that wasn't "taught" to us or we get penalized.

Comment: @boop_bop_scoop "_We have to simply work from what's available_" Since `std::vector` is available, why isn't `std::array` available? Both are part of `std`.

Answer (score 1):

When you `push_back` a pointer to a vector, you do not actually preserve the memory that this pointer points to. Therefore, this does not work here.

Instead, you should use a vector of an object which owns the `int` array, such as another `std::vector`. You only have to change two lines:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > level_collection; // CHANGED
for( auto & i : levels )
{
     auto size = std::get< 1 >(i).size();
     std::vector<int> level_data{size}; // CHANGED
     for( size_t x = 0; x < size; x ++ )
     {
          level_data[x] = std::get< 1 >(i)[x];
     }

     for( auto x : level_data)
     {
          std::cout << x << std::endl; // This works. All the values print correctly. So it did store the information as it should.
     }

     level_collection.push_back( level_data );
 }
 for( auto & i : level_collection)
 {
     std::cout << i[1] << std::endl; // This prints ALL 0s. Despite the new element not having that value.
 }
```

Note that that's assuming you actually want a two-dimensional vector. If you don't, you can just `push_back` your `int`s directly to `level_collection` which should then be defined as a `std::vector<int>`.